# Swift/SwiftUI: week/date management in swift

Tags: swift, swiftdate

I'm working on fitness app where users selects the days he wants to exercise on.

When he opens the app I wanna shown him the current week where he can observe the days his training sessions are scheduled for.

If he is from the US i wanna show him a week starting from Sunday. For EU users it should start with Monday.

Is there any way to get the "current" week dates depending on user's location/geo? Taking into account what day does the week start with in appropriate location.

Comment: You should read up on the `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find a solution for your question. I think this should work:

```
// Define a function that returns the following seven dates, given a start date
func getWeekDates(of startDate: Date, with calender: Calendar) -> [Date] {
    var weekDates: [Date] = []
    for i in 0..<7 {
        weekDates.append(calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: startDate)!)
    }
    return weekDates
}

// This should automatically take the right calendar for the user's locale
// If you want to specify the day weeks start with manually, choose .gregorian or .iso8601:
// .gregorian starts on Sunday, .iso8601 starts on Monday
let calendar = Calendar.current

let startOfCurrentWeek = calendar.date(from: calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date()))

let currentWeekDates = getWeekDates(of: startOfCurrentWeek!, with: calendar)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Calendar.current.firstWeekday
```

If it returns 1, then Sunday is the first day of week

If it returns 2, then Monday is the first day of week.

You can test this by setting locale manually

```
var calendar = Calendar.current

calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
print("\(calendar.locale!) starts on day \(calendar.firstWeekday)")
// en_GB starts on day 2

calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
print("\(calendar.locale!) starts on day \(calendar.firstWeekday)")
```